# How to restore data from damaged postgres database?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am getting this error, every time, when I'm trying to access to postgress database:

```
PANIC:  could not open critical system index 2662
```

I tried to restore system index using this manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-reindex.html
(Notes section)

But I have the same error when I enter this command:

```
sudo -u postgres  /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgres --single -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data -P database_name_1
```

I am using postgress 9.6 on centOS 7.

Please help me to restore the lost data or give some hints if you have any clues on this issue.

Comment: Restore a backup.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a backup of the data that I want to restore.

Comment: Did you run `REINDEX INDEX pg_class_oid_index` in single user mode? That's the object it complains about as far as I can tell. Could you share more about how you got the database corrupted?

Comment: I can not select my databese in single user mode. I have error: `could not open critical system index 2662` when I'm trying to do It. I have no iInforamtion about how databese became corrupted. All I know is, there was not some files in the database folder. Which I replaced from the old copy of the database.

Comment: You cannot replace missing files from an old copy of the database. Your database is irretrievably gone, and only an expensive data forensics expert may be able to salvage some of it. Files don't simply get lost. How did it happen?

Comment: As it turned out, there was a failure in the data center.